# Tokenise text and create more rows for each row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tokenize

I want to do this with `python` and `pandas`.

Let's suppose that I have the following:

```
file_id   text
1         I am the first document. I am a nice document.
2         I am the second document. I am an even nicer document.
```

and I finally want to have the following:

```
file_id   text
1         I am the first document
1         I am a nice document
2         I am the second document
2         I am an even nicer document
```

So I want the text of each file to be splitted at every fullstop and to create new lines for each of the tokens of these texts.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: u can use `nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize('text')` to split sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
s = (df.pop('text')
      .str.strip('.')
      .str.split('\.\s+', expand=True)
      .stack()
      .rename('text')
      .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

df = df.join(s).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   file_id                         text
0        1      I am the first document
1        1         I am a nice document
2        2     I am the second document
3        2  I am an even nicer document
```

**Explanation**:

First use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column, remove last `.` by  [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) and split by with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with escape `.` because special regex character, reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for Series, [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `rename` for Series for [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original.

Comment: I was waiting for you @jezrael! Thanks for the answer (upvote). Not very easily readable again (at least for a non-expert in pandas). By the way, how your answer would change If I told you that you will have also to split the text every time you encounter a newline (\n) or a forward slash (/)?

Comment: Also, by the way, would your code work if I have other columns too at the right of the text column?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - Yes, my code working with multiple columns too.

Comment: Ok, cool, I mean that I have columns at the right of the text column but I do not want to do anything particular with them except for what I did with the file_id. I only want to split the text column.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'field_id': [1,2], 
                    'text': ["I am the first document. I am a nice document.",
                             "I am the second document. I am an even nicer document."]})

df['sents'] = df.text.apply(lambda txt: [x for x in txt.split(".") if len(x) > 1])
df = df.set_index(['field_id']).apply(lambda x: 
                                      pd.Series(x['sents']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ['field_id','text']
```