# Split text in cells and create additional rows for the tokens

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's suppose that I have the following in a `DataFrame` in `pandas`:

```
id  text
1   I am the first document and I am very happy.
2   Here is the second document and it likes playing tennis.
3   This is the third document and it looks very good today.
```

and I want to split the text of each id in tokens of 3 words so I finally want to have the following:

```
id  text
1   I am the
1   first document and
1   I am very
1   happy
2   Here is the
2   second document and
2   it likes playing
2   tennis
3   This is the
3   third document and
3   it looks very
3   good today
```

Keep in mind that my dataframe may also have other columns except for these two which should be simply copied at the new dataframe in the same way as `id` above.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

I reckon that the solution to my question is quite close to the solution given here: [Tokenise text and create more rows for each row in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290155/tokenise-text-and-create-more-rows-for-each-row-in-dataframe).

This may help too: [Python: Split String every n word in smaller Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425033/python-split-string-every-n-word-in-smaller-strings).

Comment: Is that the content of the dataframe? Or just a text file?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh see my edit at the top. We are only talking about dataframes in pandas

Comment: I want to hear your opinion too on this @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self contained solution, maybe a little slower:

```
# Split every n words
n = 3

# incase id is not index yet
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)

new_df = df.text.str.split(' ', expand=True).stack().reset_index()

new_df = (new_df.groupby(['id', new_df.level_1//n])[0]
                .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
                .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         )
```

`new_df` is a series:

```
id
1               I am the
1     first document and
1              I am very
1                 happy.
2            Here is the
2    second document and
2       it likes playing
2                tennis.
3            This is the
3     third document and
3          it looks very
3            good today.
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hey thanks (upvote). It certainly looks more self-contained. However, yes, it is about how computationally expensive is too.

Comment: By the way, what happens if the dataframe has other columns too (which should be only copied as the column `id` to the new dataframe) as I write at my post? Does it still work?

Comment: it's still works if you set index as all the other columns, and replace the `reset_index(level=1)` with `reset_index(level=-1)`.

Comment: Ok cool let me see (even though I just realised that I do not really need to carry these columns to my new dataframe for now so it is ok).

Comment: Hey, I think that it actually works (!!). Great stuff. However, it returns a series (with the id as an index I think) and not a dataframe. Can you properly reset the index and create a dataframe? The dataframe should have a index column which is reset, the `id` column and the `text` column. (I do not know if this is related to this but at my actual data my `id` column is not a number but a string)

Comment: `reset_index()` on the returned series gives you a dataframe.

Comment: Cool I know this but I was just wondering if there was something that could be changed at your code above when you do this for example: `.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`. If not then apparently doing `reset_index()` at the end is reasonable.

Comment: I don't think so. `reset_index()` does not allow dropping selected levels while keeping others. Chaining is the only option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
def divide_chunks(l, n): 
    # looping till length l 
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
        yield l[i:i + n]
```

---

Then using [`unnesting`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939):

```
df['text_new']=df.text.apply(lambda x: list(divide_chunks(x.split(),3)))
df_new=unnesting(df,['text_new']).drop('text',1)
df_new.text_new=df_new.text_new.apply(' '.join)
print(df_new)
```

---

```
              text_new  id
0             I am the   1
0   first document and   1
0            I am very   1
0               happy.   1
1          Here is the   2
1  second document and   2
1     it likes playing   2
1              tennis.   2
2          This is the   3
2   third document and   3
2        it looks very   3
2          good today.   3
```

**EDIT**:

```
m=(pd.DataFrame(df.text.apply(lambda x: list(divide_chunks(x.split(),3))).values.tolist())
.unstack().sort_index(level=1).apply(' '.join).reset_index(level=1))
m.columns=df.columns
print(m)
```

---

```
   id                 text
0   0             I am the
1   0   first document and
2   0            I am very
3   0               happy.
0   1          Here is the
1   1  second document and
2   1     it likes playing
3   1              tennis.
0   2          This is the
1   2   third document and
2   2        it looks very
3   2          good today.
```

Comment: Hey thanks; it looks interesting (upvote). To be honest, I think that there will be a slightly simpler solution but I may be wrong eventually. By the way, is `unnesting` a function that you can call as you do above? I cannot find it for now.

Comment: Ah ok so you probably mean the function at the end of the answer of this link. By the way, did you see this link which I posted above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56290477/9024698? I thought that the answer there could be modified to accommodate my problem above (or not). Also @jezrael seems to be away for now so I cannot have his magic at my disposal.

Comment: Also what is the computation complexity of your solution? I think that with a nested `for` loop you could it too but perhaps it would be pretty computationally expensive. I also think that we can consider things like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425033/python-split-string-every-n-word-in-smaller-strings (if it works).

Comment: Ok let's see. To be honest, I have used the solution above (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290155/tokenise-text-and-create-more-rows-for-each-row-in-dataframe/56290477#56290477) and it worked but I did not absolutely understand it so I cannot modify it so easily to try solve my current problem.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit i have added another solution(a different approach), you can test which one is faster

Comment: Cool thanks even though the one below is significantly more self-contained and it does not seem to be that slow at my laptop. Yours may be pretty faster but still the one below is not that slow.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit Great :) i think the second approach will be faster than the first. Anyways, you are the best judge

Comment: Cool thank you in any case :) (upvoted again after your edit)