# Split sentences into substrings containing varying number of words using pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, tokenize

My question is related to this past of question of mine: [Split text in cells and create additional rows for the tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56395681/9024698).

Let's suppose that I have the following in a `DataFrame` in `pandas`:

```
id  text
1   I am the first document and I am very happy.
2   Here is the second document and it likes playing tennis.
3   This is the third document and it looks very good today.
```

and I want to split the text of each id in tokens of random number of words (varying between two values e.g. 1 and 5) so I finally want to have something like the following:

```
id  text
1   I am the
1   first document
1   and I am very
1   happy
2   Here is
2   the second document and it
2   likes playing
2   tennis
3   This is the third
3   document and
3   looks very
3   very good today
```

Keep in mind that my dataframe may also have other columns except for these two which should be simply copied at the new dataframe in the same way as `id` above.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function to extract chunks in a random fashion using `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice
import random

lo, hi = 3, 5 # change this to whatever
def extract_chunks(it):
    chunks = []
    while True:
        chunk = list(islice(it, random.choice(range(lo, hi+1))))
        if not chunk:
            break
        chunks.append(' '.join(chunk))

    return chunks
```

Call the function through a list comprehension to ensure least possible overhead, then `stack` to get your output:

```
pd.DataFrame([
    extract_chunks(iter(text.split())) for text in df['text']], index=df['id']
).stack()

id   
1   0                    I am the
    1        first document and I
    2              am very happy.
2   0                 Here is the
    1         second document and
    2    it likes playing tennis.
3   0           This is the third
    1       document and it looks
    2            very good today.
```

You can extend the `extract_chunks` function to perform tokenisation. Right now, I use a simple splitting on whitespace which you can modify.

---

Note that if you have other columns you don't want to touch, you can do something like a `melt`ing operation here.

```
u = pd.DataFrame([
    extract_chunks(iter(text.split())) for text in df['text']])

(pd.concat([df.drop('text', 1), u], axis=1)
   .melt(df.columns.difference(['text'])))
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks interesting :) (upvote) .  By the way, I would like the final output to be a common dataframe with index_reset and two columns: id and text - no multiindex etc. You could fix that for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit add .reset_index(level=1, name="text", drop=True)

Comment: By the way, are you sure about your answer to my last question? I think that the answer is `.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name="text")`. Your answer returns a series which does not have the `text` title anywhere.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit the name argument assigns a name to the series and then resets the index so the non-index column gets that name. But looking at it now you probably nailed it better. Sorry, not at my workstation.